# Stripe 'Group' Subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

Hi: I'm wondering how to create a group account for a Stripe Subscription. The idea is that an organization would provide the subscription to their employees as a benefit. The employee would sign up -- using some sort of code -- and the organization would be charged (but only when a new subscription is created). This has to be a common use case, but I Stripe support doesn't seem to understand my request. Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: So, just to clarify: when the organization originally creates their subscription, it is a zero (0) quantity per seat monthly subscription...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to model this and it's partly up to you to decide based on how you want to charge them. the most common ways would be to have one subscription where the `quantity` represents the number of "users" at that company. You separately track each user in your own system when they sign up, when they cancel, and you update the `quantity` on the subscription to represent that.

Comment: Thanks @koopajah. So it's possible to create a 0 quantity monthly subscription? I don't know how many users will participate to start with. I agree I would need to manage that outside of script, but I'm still not sure how to create a 0 quantity monthly subscription.

Comment: yes it's possible, you can test this in a few seconds in Test mode to confirm!